# Networkx shortest paths for two point layers

Tags: python, graph, geometry, distance, networkx

I have a task to know the best way from houses to subway station.

[image]

There are three types of data on a picture below:

- orange dots are the entrances to subway stations
- violet dots are centerspoints of houses
- blue lines is a road network (let it firstly contain all types of
  road data)

The goal is to determine the shortest path from every house point to the closest subway entry and build a polyline layer.
I was thinking of using `arcpy` library for that but recently heard about `networkx` module, but right now I know only how to load data in graph, however, I cannot figure out how to look for desirable shortest path and what to do next in general.

Here is my draft for loading data to nx.Multigraph():

```
import arcpy
import networkx as nx 
import numpy as np

line_fc = 'lines'
points_hs = 'house_points'

graph = nx.MultiGraph()
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(line_fc, 'SHAPE@') as sc:
    for row in sc:
        line_geom = row[0].getPart(0)
        list_geom_cors = np.array([(n.X, n.Y) for n in line_geom])
        graph.add_edges_from(list_geom_cors)

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(points_hs, 'SHAPE@XY') as sc:
    for row in sc:
        graph.add_node(row[0])
```

How to perform this task as correctly as possible?

Comment: Do I understand correctly: you have the graph loaded in.  For each house you want the path to the nearest subway station?  If so, does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51864929/2966723

Comment: @Joel yes, that's right. But I am not sure that my code with uploading data into the graph is right.

Comment: If you add an edge to a graph and any of the nodes don't exist then they will be added to the graph nodes automatically.

Comment: If you are going to run `shortest_path` on this network, then you should be aware that the networkx searches for the shortest path measured in the integer number of edges (by default), not the geometric distance between the nodes. To get the shortest path measured in total distance transversed in the real world, you would have to add weights to your edges that indicate the length of each edge (assuming edges have different length in your problem).